# Selenium waitFor commands not waiting

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-ide

I am relatively new to Selenium. I am using Selenium IDE to test the front-end of a web-integrated BPM database.

I cannot seem to get the Selenium IDE "waitFor..." commands (any of them) to actually wait. I am having this issue with waitForPageToLoad, waitForPopup, waitForElementPresent, waitForVisible etc. Selenium just seems to skip over them (they always pass, execution does not wait).

As a consequence I am having to use the "pause" command to get execution to wait until the elements are "interactable", which is obviously a bad way of doing things.

```
<tr>
  <td>openWindow</td>
  <td>http://test.web.adress/eForm.aspx?Map=UserSearchAdminGroup&amp;...</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>selectPopUp</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
  <td>id=pnlSearchIn_txtMetastormUserName_Editor</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>type</td>
  <td>id=pnlSearchIn_txtMetastormUserName_Editor</td>
  <td>Vorster</td>
</tr>
```

In the example above, Selenium runs and passes the "waitForElementPresent" command, but does not wait, and consequently tries to type into a textbox that has not yet loaded.

I have searched extensively for an answer, but cannot find anything about anyone else having the same issue... Which makes me think think that I am making a simple mistake somewhere... ;)

Any help / advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you get an error on the type command? I'd wager you aren't.

I think your waitFor shouldn't be for Presence since the element DOES exist in the dom. Sounds like you want to wait for an attribute, or style,  on the element.

Comment: maybe try waitForEditable?